# If the Warlord destroys a player's eighth district, does the game still end?

Tags: citadels

In *Citadels*, if the Warlord destroys a player's eighth district, assuming no other players have eight districts, does the game still end at the end of the round?

If so, does that player still get the "first to build eight districts" bonus points?

What if on the last round, Alfred finishes eight districts, Betty finishes eight districts, and Charlie Warlords one of Alfred's districts.  Who gets what bonus points here?  Alfred was the first to build eight districts, but does not *have* eight districts at the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the Warlord is not allowed to destroy a building if that person already has 8 built.

Comment: Right. The actual wording is that the Wardlord cannot destroy from a completed district, so 7 districts with a bell tower is also immune as outlined [here](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Citadels/support/citadels-faq.pdf)

Comment: Huh.  Missed that someplace.

Answer (score 7):

Warlord is not authorised to attack a finished city.

Nevertheless, the rules says that we finish the turn and end the game once someone reach 8 buildings (as opposed to "game is finished if, at the end of turn, someone has 8 buildings"), so if you use this card (I don't remember the name) who can be sacrificed to destroy a building, my thought is that the game still end at the end of the turn. Same thing if you use the card that reduce the number of buildings to finish by one (note that a 7-building city will be considered as finished and the warlord can't attack it).

The bonus is granted to the first one, so in your example (if we use the card to destroy a building, not the warlord) Alfred got the bonus for having finished first, he doesn't get the 5-color bonus if he had it before his 8th building was destroyed and not after that.

Comment: The card is Armoury (possibly Powderhouse in some versions).

Answer (score 1):

Once somebody builds eight districts, it triggers end end of game to finish the current round. This trigger cannot be undone. The rules do also state that the warlord may not destroy a building of the player who triggered this event.